# CROS-ORIGIN request with ngResource on mobile

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, ngresource

When I send request with desktop browser I work just fine but when I send when mobile response is like this:
[image: OPTION REQ]

[image: GET REQ]

Here is my resource code:

```
app.factory('Category', function($resource) {

    return {
        get: $resource('example.com/user/profile/category', null, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET', 
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                responseType: 'json',
                transformResponse: [],
            }
        }),
    }
});
```

This problem only appear on mobile! When I use desktop every thing is ok!
By the way why when browser in mobile send option req there is response(in text type) but on desktop response is empty?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `transformResponse: [],` we should remove it!